# how does second term of advertise

Tags: ros, queue, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.
I'm writing a program that reads data from a laser. This information is published by stage or a bag file.
I know that the second parameter of the function advertise() or subscribe() is the size of the message queue, but how does this value?
for example, I have assigned 50 but in other examples value turns to 10 ,
How does this changes affect the program?

Thanks in advance,
azucena

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9532/how-does-second-term-of-advertise/) by [Azucena](https://answers.ros.org/users/336/azucena/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-03-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe you're talking about the queue size parameter in roscpp.  From the [roscpp overview](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers):

**for publishing**

> queue_size [required]
>
> This is the size of the outgoing
> message queue. If you are publishing
> faster than roscpp can send the
> messages over the wire, roscpp will
> start dropping old messages. A value
> of 0 here means an infinite queue,
> which can be dangerous.

**for subscribing**

> queue_size
>
> This is the incoming message queue size roscpp will use for your
> callback. If messages are arriving too
> fast and you are unable to keep up,
> roscpp will start throwing away
> messages. A value of 0 here means an
> infinite queue, which can be
> dangerous.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-12-28**:
Does that mean if the parameter is set to 1, then, only 1 old message is put in queue every time, and next time step, the stored 1 old message is replaced with another one and so on?